# Multiple simultaneous ESP32 BLE connections to one mobile device

Tags: esp32, bluetooth-low-energy, android

I'm trying to find out if it's possible for at least two ESP32's to maintain active BLE connections with one Android mobile device at the same time.

What I'm basically trying to do is to send analog sensor data from 2 different sensors to an android app on my phone, at the same time.

Any links to relevant Arduino and Android libraries will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The mobile device connects to the esp32s. Yes it’s kosher BLE operation. You might be able to use webBle to connect via the browser and avoid any native code shenanigans. Nordic have some apps to make debug easier.

Answer (score 2):

It’s possible. But you could also consider making the phone the slave and update by the esp’s as masters. It’s only a blink to send the analog data, time/date if necessary and it can be send as long as there is that slave available.